# Cross query between azure sql databases using external table

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have a problem with creating a cross query db between azure sql databases
using external table.

this is the error i get:

```
An error occurred while establishing connection to remote data source: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'CrossQueryUser'.[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'CrossQueryUser'.
```

I am not sure what i have done wrong?
I followed the this link:
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/cross-database-queries-in-azure-sql-database

and here are my scripts:

-- master db

```
CREATE LOGIN CrossQueryUser WITH PASSWORD = 'SOMEPASSWORD'
```

-- Destination DB for query (where the destination table is on)

```
CREATE USER CrossQueryUser FOR LOGIN CrossQueryUser
GO
GRANT SELECT TO CrossQueryUser
GO
GRANT EXECUTE TO CrossQueryUser
```

-- Source DB for query

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL CrossQueryCredential 
  WITH IDENTITY = 'CrossQueryUser', SECRET = 'somepassword'
```

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE SQLQueryDB
 WITH 
 ( TYPE = RDBMS,
   LOCATION='******.database.windows.net',
   DATABASE_NAME = 'somedb_Stg',
   CREDENTIAL = CrossQueryCredential
 );
```

```
-- Create the external destination table in Source DB 
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[sometable](
   [Id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
   [InstrumentId] [int] NOT NULL,
   [AskRate] [decimal](36, 18) NOT NULL,
   [BidRate] [decimal](36, 18) NOT NULL,
   [CurrencyRateProviderId] [int] NOT NULL,
   [DateFrom] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
   [DateTo] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
   [Symbol] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
   [Name] [varchar](64) NOT NULL
) WITH (DATA_SOURCE = SQLQueryDB)
GO
```

```
select * from [dbo].[sometable]
```

Many thanks

Comment: What flavor of Azure SQL Database is this?  I'm surprised you're creating a Login instead of a User with a password.  Can you use those credentials to connect from SSMS?

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your response. The error was in the login as stated. apparently there was an incorrect login.

Comment: So you fixed the login and your problem is solved?

Comment: Hey, I got a admin user with password. used this user and password for the information of the "Database scoped credential" - Identity = {adminuser} SECRET = {adminpassword}. in essence skipped the creation of login user as i already got one on server level.